# Relaciones en laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, vistas, model

Buenas, tengo una vista donde recibo una "id de asignatura", "id de alumno" y quiero mostrar las calificaciones que tenga ESE alumno en ESA ASIGNATURA.

tengo la siguiente funcion

```
 public function verCalificacion($id, $idasi)
{
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($idasi); 
    $mis_notas = $alumno->calificaciones; // ????

    return view('datos-profesor.vercalificacion')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('mis_notas',$mis_notas)->with('asignatura',$asignatura);
}
```

donde recibo las ids correspondientes, pero nose como usar la relacion para que me devuelva las calificaciones de un alumno en una asignatura, en la tabla Calificaciones de la base de datos tengo las ids foraneas correspondientes y estas son las relaciones

Calificacion

```
public function alumno()
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class, 'id_alumno', 'id');
}


public function asignatura()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Asignatura::class, 'id_asignatura', 'id');
}
```

Alumno

```
public function calificaciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Calificacion','id_alumno');
}
```

Asignatura

```
public function calificaciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Calificacion','id_asignatura');
}
```

intente un par de wheres pero no me resulta, quien puede ayudarme porfavor. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Las relaciones están bien en los modelos entonces como estas trabajando con ORM no hace falta `$asignatura = Asignatura::find($idasi);`

En tu vista directamente puedes acceder ella desde la variable `$alumno`

Ejemplo:

```
@foreach($alumno->calificaciones as $calificacion)
     {{ $calificacion->asignatura->nombre_asignatura }}
@foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
$alumno = DB::table('alumnos as a')
            ->join('calificaciones as cal', 'a.atributo_llaveforanea', '=', 'cal.llave_foranea')
            ->orderBy('idalumno', 'desc')
            ->get();
        return view('datos-profesor.vercalificacion', ["calificaciones" => $alumno]);
```

Donde `a.atributo_llaveforanea` y `a.atributo_llaveforanea` son los atributos relacionados.

No olvides incluir la clase `use DB;` al inicio de tu controlador

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero segun yo, ese join solo me mostrara las calificaciones del alumno, no las calificaciones del alumno en una asignatura.